# Tweepy twitter bot how to prevent duplicate tweets within a time period

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have the following tweepy Twitter bot that posts a random image and caption from a Json file. What I would like to do is prevent a duplicate tweet from happening in a given time period (24 hours) or a given number of messages(10). Any help would be kindly appreciated!

```
import schedule
import time
import tweepy
import random
import json
with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    info = json.load(f)
    
def job():
    print("I'm working...")

    CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXXXX'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXXXX'
    ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXX'
    ACCESS_SECRET = 'XXXXXX'

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)


    randomChoice = random.randrange(len(info))
    print (info[randomChoice])
    api.update_with_media(info[randomChoice]['image'], status=info[randomChoice]['text']) 

schedule.every(30).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```